# MATCH and INDEX for Range that consists of multiple Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get your help!

I have an Excel file in which Sheet1 consists of multiple cells.
My lookup_value is C4. C4 is a value that is calculated with the following formula

```
=LARGE(04:T4,1)
```

where

04 - T4 are located in Sheet1 and represent the five largest values of a "defined" range called "myRange"`

```
=LARGE("myRange",1) ...  =LARGE("myRange",5)
```

"myRange" is located in Sheet2 and is writtten as:

```
=Sheet2!$N$2:$N$100,Sheet2!$AA$2:$AA$100,Sheet2!$AN$2:$AN$100,Sheet2!$BA$2:$BA$100,Sheet2!$BN$2:$BN$100)
```

I use "myRang" as the lookup_array

Now I would like to use a formula to retrieve the cell that is 11 columns to the left of the cell in my lookup_array that is equal to C4. So, this cell could in column C/P/AC/AP/BC or BP in Sheet2

I have named this range "TargetRange"

`=Sheet2!$C$2:$C$100,Sheet2!$P$2:$P$100,Sheet2!$AC$2:$AC$100,Sheet2!$BC$2:$BC$10,Sheet2!$BP$2:$BP$100,)`

If I use the formula

```
=INDEX("TargetRange,MATCH(C4,"myRange))
```

I get N/A. Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: for starters the formula contains an error, check your quotation marks which I'm pretty sure you don't need, and should be : `Index(TargetRange,MATCH(C4,myRange))`

Comment: Also, your `Large` function should not be range `04:T4` but `O4:T4`, right?

Comment: Pull apart your function in to its constituents (i.e., examine the `Match` function and see if that is the source of the error. (Hint: it is, because Match only works against a single row or column, and you've defined `myRange` as a range of multiple, non-contiguous columns.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I believe I need to use an array function.

I use the following code:

=INDEX(TargetRange,MAX(IF(myRange=C4,COLUMN(TargetRange)))). However, I get #VALUE!. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify whether all values in myRange contain a number? If so, are these numbers always non-negative?